# Lines disappearing after rotation in tikz 3d

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to plot a cube with two vectors inside in `tikz`, but I rotated the axis so that it becomes more readable. However, some of the lines that I plotted (and showed before the z-axis rotation) have disappeared. Can someone explain? It looks like there is a surface plotted on top of them.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    rotate around z=-90,
    xmin=-1, ymin=-1,
    xmax=1, ymax=1,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, axis z line=middle,
]
% plotting the edges
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(1,1,1) (-1,1,1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(1,1,1) (1,-1,1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(1,1,1) (1,1,-1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(-1,1,1) (-1,1,-1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(-1,-1,1) (-1,1,1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(-1,-1,-1) (-1,1,-1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(-1,-1,-1) (1,-1,-1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(-1,-1,1) (1,-1,1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(-1,1,-1) (1,1,-1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(1,1,-1) (1,-1,-1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(1,-1,1) (1,-1,-1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(1,1,-1) (1,-1,-1)};
\addplot3[no marks] coordinates {(-1,-1,1) (-1,-1,-1)};

% plotting the vectors
\draw[->, ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,1) node[pos=1.02,anchor=south]{$\bm{v}$};
\draw[->, ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,1) node[pos=1.02,anchor=south]{$\bm{w}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: myplot]

I would not mind getting some insight as to how to remove the `0.5`s that somehow only show on the x-axis and make so that the cube is not as stretched as it currently is.